# xkb configuration to map Alt + h --> Right

Tags: keyboard-layout, chromebook, xkb

I have a Chromebook that's missing a number of vital keys.  I'd like to remap those to ones that are present.  Unfortunately the Chromebook has a dearth of keys in general so I need to map a combination of keys to a single one.  One example would be mapping `Alt h` to `End`

Xorg keyboard stuff seems to be in a state of transition right now with a lot of older methods being depreciated (keymaps, xmodmaps, etcs)

From what I've gleaned the correct way of changing your keyboard map system wide, is trough xbk.  There are a number of examples of people mapping a single key say a caps lock to be a shift key just by modifying the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file.  There are also some examples of how to create a fully customized key using setxkmap.  But I haven't found any examples of how best to map a key combination to a single key.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you want that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> map to <kbd>End</kbd> or to <kbd>→</kbd>
But I know how to do it with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> instead..
Anyway it is not a good idea to remap Alt since it is often used in programs..
Try this in your symbol file:

```
key <AC06> { [ h , H , End ] }; // Map <AltGr>+<H> to <End>
```

or

```
key <AC06> { [ h , H , Right ] }; // Map <AltGr>+<H> to <→>
```

But maybe this is not what you want..
But I'm also interested about the mapping of modifiers..
I try to make <kbd>Space</kbd> acting as a modifier..

Comment: but this will map `AltGr`+`h`to (effectively) `AltGr`+`end`, not just `end`, right?